# Laravel upload and validate apk file

Tags: laravel, file-upload, apk

I need to upload an apk file into my laravel application and i have this rule for request validation but getting invalid data type error when uploading an apk file.

```
        return [
        'app'=>'required|mimes:application/vnd.android.package-archive,apk'
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to specify mimes with apk.

```
return [
        'app'=>'required|mimes:application/vnd.android.package-archive'
    ];
```

or go with root functionality

```
'app' => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => 'QuickDrive.apk',
     'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
     'size' => 95585970,
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to append `apk`, use the following code snippet

`return ['app'=>'required|mimes:application/vnd.android.package-archive'];`

See [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#basic-usage-of-mime-rule), and [Full listing of MIME types](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types)

Comment: Hi thanks , but still having data type error

Comment: Can you show me the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Based on how the os or the Laravel recognizes your `mime`;

linux command:
`file -b --mime app.apk`
result:`application/zip`

Or

Laravel: `$file->getMimeType()` result:`application/zip`

You have to put `zip` on validation rules.

```
        return [
            'app'=>'required|mimes:zip'
        ];
```